# Installing Drupal: Database configuration problem

Tags: installation, drupal

I am trying to install Drupal 6.16 on a clean website.

I get through the "Verify Requirements" page easily.

On the Database Configuration, I supply all the proper info, but "Save and Continue" returns me back to the same page, with no error message.  I am unable to proceed past this point.

I've verified my info with the ISP, including a non-local database host (under Advanced Options), and that the database user has full DBA rights.

The lack of an error message is particularly frustrating.
Do you have any ideas what the problem is, or how to pursue it and resolve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had the exact same problem...in my case, it was because Drupal expects you to copy the default.settings.php file to settings.php, not just rename it. Ensure you have both files and you should be good to go.